# Symfony mod_rewrite only main route works

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, symfony

I wanted to use mod_rewrite. I have in /var/www/.htaccess this code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    #AllowOverride All

    #Allow from All  
    #RewriteBase /WorldClock
    #RewriteBase WorldClock/web/app.php
    # Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
    RewriteRule ^/web/app_dev.php - [L]
    RewriteRule ^/web/app.php - [L]

    # Fix the bundles folder
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ WorldClock/web/app.php/test [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # Change below before deploying to production
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ WorldClock/web/app.php [QSA,L]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ WorldClock/web/app_dev.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

If line is comment, that mean it made **Internal Server Error**
My project is in `/var/www/WorldClock/..` Folder with css|js|img i shifted to `/var/www`
If I try to get in `localhost` then it works fine. But if I click in link and get url like this `http://localhost/info/12` then I get

```
 Not Found The requested URL /info.xml/12 was not found on this server.
```

Everything works fine without .htaccess. Mod_rewrite is on in phpinfo(); I use symfony2 and Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

For us to be able to help, at the very least we need your web server's config. I assume this is simply a matter of the web server not being configured properly. If I'm off with my answer, please update your question with meaningful error messages, i.e. check your error.log and a more detailed description of which routes work and which don't, as I am not entirely sure whether you can access localhost and see the default "It work's" page or your project's frontpage and whether you can access your assets or not?

Just create a new file `worldclock.conf` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/WorldClock/web
    <Directory /var/www/WorldClock/web>
        # enable the .htaccess rewrites
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now you just have to enable the new virtual host and restart your web server:

```
sudo a2ensite worldclock

# When both hosts use localhost as ServerName there might be some problems
# so we'll disable the default host, which we won't need anyway(?)
sudo adissite default

sudo service apache2 restart
```

If this is only your development environment you could use PHP's internal web server (assuming you have 5.4 installed) which will ease up some of the work required, as you only have to run: `php app/console server:run` to get it running. Then you can access your app via: `http://localhost:8000` by default.

To find out which PHP version is installed just run: `php -v` in your terminal.